# Saving a file (or data) to an iOS device so that it can be read on the app startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file-io

I've been trying to find some kind of tutorial or information of any kind on some sort of file being read on app startup.

The scenario would be:

1. App Starts up
2. App checks for for file on iOS device hard drive to determine existing settings
3. If there are no existing settings, the app will then take data in and create existing settings, and save it to the iOS device to be read upon app startup the next time the app is run.

I tried to be as clear as possible.  If this does not make sense, let me know and I will try to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For user settings, use NSUserDefaults.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

But you don't need to check whether the app has been run.

NSUserDefaults allows you to register a set of defaults that will only apply if they have not been overwritten, either in a Settings.bundle via the settings app or directly in NSUserDefaults within your app.

So, define a `initialiseUserDefaults` method and call it at app startup.

```
- (void)initialiseUserDefaults
{
    NSDictionary *regDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"userPref1",
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"userPref2",
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"userPref3",
                         nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:regDict];
}
```

(You could get you defaults from wherever you choose.)

I hope that helps.

Comment: This seems to be the direction I would want to go.  However, if the defaults are changed by the app, the UserDefaults become overwritten, correct?  If they become overwritten, are the UserDefaults still checked when the app starts up?  The goal would be to check the UserDefaults when the app starts up.  The App will perform "X" OR "Y" OR "Z" depending on the values of the UserDefaults.  Does this make sense?  Does this sound accurate and in the realm of possibility as it pertains to UserDefaults?

Comment: @Skizz NSUserDefaults will be checked as and when you wish — what registerDefaults does is allow you to specify the "unless I say otherwise" option — i.e. what you might think of as the genuine default. Clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

[For user settings, use NSUserDefaults.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Create a key of `appHasRun` as a bool and check if it is `true`. If so, they have run the app before. If it is `false`, set all of the default settings and set `appHasRun` to `true`.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![prefs boolForKey:@"appHasRun"]){
  /* Set Default Settings HERE */
  [prefs setBool:true forKey:@"appHasRun"];
  [prefs syncronize];
}
```